# In tkinter .destroy() function would not work

Tags: python, tkinter

I used .destroy to delete some widgets in my projects but the code would not destroy those widgets, no error log is generated either. What can be the reason? Earlier it used to destroy but now its not working.

```
def play_music(song_path, song_name):
    global stop_btn
    stop_btn = Button(main_window, image=Stop, border=0, bg="Gray1", activebackground="Gray1", command=stop_music)
    stop_btn.place(x=532, y=675)
    main_window.bind("<BackSpace>", stop_music)

    global pause_btn
    pause_btn = Button(main_window, image=Pause, border=0, bg="Gray1", activebackground="Gray1",
                       command=lambda: pause_music(paused))
    pause_btn.place(x=588, y=675)
    main_window.bind("<space>", lambda x: pause_music(paused))

    global next_btn
    next_btn = Button(main_window, image=Next, border=0, bg="Gray1", activebackground="Gray1", command=previous_song)
    next_btn.place(x=643, y=675)
    main_window.bind("<Left>", previous_song)

    global previous_btn
    previous_btn = Button(main_window, image=Previous, border=0, bg="Gray1", activebackground="Gray1",
                          command=next_song)
    previous_btn.place(x=475, y=675)
    main_window.bind("<Right>", next_song)

    global song_slider
    style1 = ttk.Style()
    style1.configure("myStyle.Horizontal.TScale", background="gray1")
    song_slider = ttk.Scale(main_window, from_=0, to=est_length, command=song_slide, length=980,
                            style="myStyle.Horizontal.TScale")
    song_slider.place(x=100, y=640)

    global volume_slider
    volume_slider = ttk.Scale(main_window, from_=0, to=1, orient=HORIZONTAL, value=volume_set, command=volume_control,
                              length=120, style="myStyle.Horizontal.TScale")
    volume_slider.place(x=150, y=675)

def stop_music(*args):
    global play
    play = False
    mixer.music.stop()


    previous_btn.destroy()
    next_btn.destroy()
    pause_btn.destroy()
    volume_slider.destroy()
    stop_btn.destroy()
    song_slider.destroy()
```

Comment: take your time to read the link: [How to create minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you call `play_music()` more than once before calling `stop_music()`, then the mentioned issue will happen.

Comment: @acw1668 Is there any way to fix that like if I call `play_music()` more than once and still when I call `stop_music()` it should work. Is this possible?

Comment: I would suggest to create those widgets once outside `play_music()` and don't destroy them inside `stop_music()`.